# iOS Development: All I need to do is post a tweet

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I've been researching the latest ways to integrate Twitter into my app and it appears the best (most painless) approach is to use the MGTwitterEngine, and the best tutorial I could find to implement this is [a 3-part series](http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-part-1/).  If all I need to do is allow the user to login to their twitter account and post a single tweet that's always the same, is there an easier way to do that than following the tutorial I linked to?

Thanks so much for your wisdom.  If the alternatives aren't much easier, no problem, I'm not so lazy that I can't follow a tutorial, I was just wondering if there's a quicker way that I didn't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of st3fan's (Stefan Arentz) https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter project. It's very easy to integrate and includes whole views that you can just use, easily customizable too.

Plan your Twitter implementation ahead - with an iPhone project you will want to use xAuth authentication which does not require a round trip to the web browser.* You have to first register your app and then request permission for your application to use this method. Check the [Twitter developer pages](http://dev.twitter.com/) for more details.

*or not. But I hate leaving the app to post tweets.

Comment: overkill for what he wants, IMO.

Comment: The good thing about this solution is the user doesn't have to leave the app to post the tweet.  The downside is it uses xAuth, which I have to request permission to use and I have no idea how long that will take to get, if ever.

Comment: I've done it for two apps. The first time it took two nights (I am in Australia) because I did not know exactly what to say. The second time overnight.

Comment: @AdamEberbach i am getting this error Client application is not permitted to use xAuth. although i have provided `kOAuthConsumerKey` and `kOAuthConsumerSecret` whats problem here? and also this error `Request failed with status code 401`

Answer (score 2):

Create a button that opens a `UIWebView` when clicked. Build the URL using details here: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton. Simple - about 10 lines of code.

Comment: thanks, psychotik.  i assume the UIWebView is to allow the user to login?  also, is there a way to confirm the tweet was actually posted?  thanks again!

Comment: Well, there is but it's a little tricky. What you need to do is to display a UIWebView as a popup and set your class as the delegate. Then, you get callbacks before/after each page load and you can interpret the success/cancel URIs from Twitter. I don't have this code handy, but look as Facebook's open source iPhone SDK. It uses this trick -- just modify the URLs and you're good to go.